# How to set logical operators as function`s arguments in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, logical-operators

is there a way how to have logical operators ( =, <= etc...) as a function argument that is changeble?

let say we want to write easy function calculator when you give 2 numbers as arguments and operator such as = or >= etc. also as argument

Answer (score 1):

These operators are functions inside backticks ``` `` ```.

Let's say the function is

```
my_calculator <- function(f,v1,v2) { return(f(v1,v2)) }
```

Then I can do

```
my_calculator(`==`,3,4)
my_calculator(`+`,3,4)
my_calculator(`-`,3,4)
```

etc.
Does it answer your question?